# Unable to select row where uuid = (number)

Tags: mysql, sql, uuid

So i'm trying to lookup a uuid in my database but when i try to select it it gives me this error

```
SELECT (`udid`, 1, 100) FROM `payments` 
WHERE `udid` = 584BA8D699204951B0B4C1591728E88E LIMIT 0, 25
```

1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

ive tried making the limit 100 chars but as u can see same error

```
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
udid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
paid BOOLEAN
```

Comment: Could we see the table layout? Also, are you executing this statement from another application, or inside the mysql console?

Could we also get the complete error message?

Comment: just added and yes from mysql console

Comment: your post title says uuid but your SQL says udid. Is that intentional?

Comment: i wrote uuid to make it easier to understand udid is just a device specfic id from iphones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT `udid`, 1, 100 FROM `payments` WHERE `udid` = "584BA8D699204951B0B4C1591728E88E" LIMIT 0, 25
```

Removing the '(' ')' from around '`udid`, 1, 100' was the fix, however you also needed to quote your strings.